# New hourly rate after a pay raise

Tags: arithmetic

> Show the correct equation and solve for the indicated items.
>
> Jim is earning $12.50 per hour as a cook. He has earned an 8.5% pay raise this year. What will his new hourly rate be?

Source: http://www.transtutors.com/questions/story-problem-in-math-335280.htm

Comment: Does one _really_ get 3 dollars for answering this question?  I find that hard to believe.  But, if it were true, by crowdsourcing, we don't even need to know any maths to make money.  We can just copy/paste the questions here, and copy/paste the answers back for profit.  Nice!

Answer (score 3):

Increment in a year implies proportionate increment in month, day, hour as well .

So, the new rate should be $$12.5\left(1+\frac{8.5}{100}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Jim is earning $12.5*24*365$ a year.

Now raise $= \frac{8.5}{100}*12.5*24*365$ , new yearly payment $= \frac{8.5}{100}*12.5*24*365+12.5*24*365$ = $12.5*24*365(1+\frac{8.5}{100})$

Therefore new per hour income will be = $$\frac{12.5*24*365(1+\frac{8.5}{100})}{24*365}$$

which is equal to $12.5.(1+\frac{8.5}{100})$